# Вешние ключи DataTable

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Есть ли в ADO.NET возможность узнать о наличии внешних ключей у таблицы? Например, узнать поле с первичным ключом можно с помощью адаптера, указав в его свойство `MissingSchemaAction` значение `MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey`. В случае с внешним ключом придётся загружать всю базу данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно узнать через метаданные таблицы, использую для этого sql, при этом ненужно будет грузить всю базу.

Пример кода для MSSQL

```
declare @tableId int = object_id('<Название таблицы>')
select col.name from sys.foreign_key_columns fk inner join sys.columns col on 
fk.parent_column_id = col.column_id where fk.parent_object_id = @tableId and col.object_id = @tableId
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста